# Syntax quirks or why is that valid python

Tags: python, syntax

In python 2.6, why is the following line valid?

```
my_line = 'foo' 'bar'
```

and if that is valid, why isn't the following:

```
my_list = 1 2
```

The first example is string concatenation, however, the following isn't valid either (thanks god):

```
foo = 'foo'
bar = 'bar'
foo_bar = foo bar
```

Comment: I don't see the point in "removing" white spaces as your `my_list= 1 2` example seems to suggest.

Comment: It doesn't suggest that. What I suggest is that this aspect of Python syntax is inconsistent (imho).

Comment: See this PEP http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3126/ where it is discussed extensively.

Comment: In any language, I suspect that 5 * 10 is valid but "foo" * "bar" is not. Does that make the language inconsistent? Even if so, what does that matter?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is doing [string literal concatenation](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation).  As noted in the documentation, advantages include the following:

> This feature can be used to reduce the
>   number of backslashes needed, to split
>   long strings conveniently across long
>   lines, or even to add comments to
>   parts of strings...

It goes on to note that this concatenation is done *at compilation time* rather than run time.

The history and rationale behind this, and a rejected suggestion to remove the feature, is described in [PEP 3126](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3126/).

Answer (score 8):

`my_line = 'foo' 'bar'` is string concatenation.

Comment: @Ipthnc me too.  Luckily I haven't come across code written this way, and I hope I never have to... I'm sure I'll forget what the heck it means!

Comment: It might be useful when "auto-generating" code but aside from this, I fail to see the advantage (if any).

Comment: C and C++ do this too. I don't know of any really good reason for Python to have the same quirk. In this particular case, `'foo' + 'bar'` compiles to exactly the same bytecode, but IIRC the bytecode compiler does not *always* constant-fold string addition.

Comment: This basically looks like an operation is done (string concat) without the use of any operator or function. I know this is valid Python, but cannot imagine why anyone would want this, let alone have it work on types other than strings.

Comment: When generating Python code programmatically, issuing the the fragment `"fragment1"` semi-independently from another fragment `"fragment"` on the same line is easier than having to track another state in an FSM to account for open-close string literal.

Comment: @Jason, I believe that's false, as this is done at compilation time, not run time.  See my answers for a link that shows good reasons for having this feature.

Comment: It's so you can break up strings across multiple lines. You can do something like `my_str = ('A really long string that's hard to fit on a line ' \n 'combined with another really long string on another line.'`) (Can't do proper formatting in comments, but imagine that spans two lines.) It's actually pretty useful and fairly common in Python source code. For what it's worth, C/C++ allow the same sort of automatic string concatenation.

Comment: @jldupont, one down-side of triple-quoted strings is that they include whitespace from any indentation.  That would often force you to left-align everything in them, which can often break up the "flow" of code for the reader.  I use triple-quoted strings for multiline constants, defined outside of classes or functions, but inside either I usually prefer the string concatentation approach.

Comment: @Peter Hansen: that makes sense. I remember using docstrings in unconventional ways in the past and I had to do "editing on-the-fly" but chose docstring anyways because they are easier to read. I guess there are many ways to skin a cat.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps this is of C's ancestry. In C, the following is perfectly valid:

```
char* ptr = "hello " "world";
```

It is implemented by the C [pre-processor (cpp)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#String_literal_concatenation), and the rationale given in that link is:

> this allows long strings to be split
>   over multiple lines, and also allows
>   string literals resulting from C
>   preprocessor defines and macros to be
>   appended to strings at compile time

Answer (score 5):

It isn't inconsistent.  Strings and integers have different methods.

Integer concatenation is meaningless.

String concatenation is a meaningful default behavior.