# Pythonic way of writing a single-line long string

Tags: python, string

What is the Pythonic way of writing a single-line but long string in program:

```
s = 'This is a long long string.'
```

Additionally, the string may need to be formatted with variables:

```
s = 'This is a {} long long string.'.format('formatted')
```

### Existing Solution 1

```
s = 'This is a long '\
        'long '\
        'string.'
```

Additional trailing `\` characters make reformatting very difficult. Joining two lines with a `\` gives an error.

### Existing Solution 2

```
s = 'This is a long \
long \
string.'
```

Except for a similar problem as above, subsequent lines must be aligned at the very beginning, which gives awkward readability when the first line is indented.

Comment: Not a duplicate.. this appears to be about single line long strings, while that stackoverflow question is for multi-line strings.

Comment: @chris I don't think this is a duplicate to the other question being referenced. This is about single-line strings, not multi-line ones.

Comment: Agree with @rgilligan – the question being referred to is for *multi-line* strings, please re-open this question.

Comment: I actually voted to close this as primarily opinion-based, not as a duplicate of that question. I agree that it is different. However, this _has_ been asked before, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058925/how-can-i-break-up-this-long-line-in-python. It probably shouldn't be reopened.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For long strings where you don't want \n characters, use 'string literal concatenation':

```
s = (
    'this '
    'is '
    'a '
    'long '
    'string')
```

Output:

> This is a long string

And it can be formatted as well:

```
s = (
    'this '
    'is '
    'a '
    '{} long '
    'string').format('formatted')
```

Output:

> This is a formatted long string

Comment: [Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation).

Comment: This one looks the best at the moment, but it doesn't work with formatting command in text editors such as vim's `gq` when you modify the string. Also, you may need to write multiple `.format`, one for each element you need to format.

Comment: @Cyker: That is incorrect, you only write one `.format()`.

Comment: @rgilligan All right. It works and by giving it a second look I now understand why. This looks cool. Thank you very much.

Comment: @rgilligan However, I want to point that you need trailing spaces in each string element as Python doesn't interpolate them automatically.

Comment: @DietrichEpp That's true. In the very end of the string. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @Cyker thanks, I updated the answer to reflect those things.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the PEP8 guideline:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length

Wrap long lines in parenthesis.

Use a maximum of 72 characters per line for long lines of text.

If you have any operators in your string, place the line breaks before them.

Other than that, as long as you're not obscuring what's going on, it's pretty much up to you on how you want to do it.