# Adding linebreaks to string and then rendering linebreaks

Tags: django

I'm attempting to build a linebreak into a string and then render that string in a template with the linebreaks. I'm saving the following string to a model field:

```
usercart.other_tax_regnum = "State tax reg number" + "/n" + "Second State tax reg number"  
usercart.save()
```

Then, within my view, I render thefield

```
 {{ usercart.other_tax_regnum|linebreaks }}
```

Rather than showing a line break, this is what gets rendered:

```
State tax reg number/nSecond State tax reg number
```

Any thoughts on how I can do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a little mistake:

**Right:**

```
\n
```

**Wrong:**

```
/n
```

There is also different ways:

[Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058925/how-can-i-break-up-this-long-line-in-python)