# PyCharm: HTML Syntax checking and highlighting in Python strings

Tags: python, html, pycharm, syntax-highlighting

Example:

```html
@register.simple_tag
def last_orders(user):
    rows = []
    for order in Order.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-offer__date'):
        rows.append(format_html('<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{} Eur</td><td class="int col-1">{}</td><td>{} Eur</td></div>',
                                order.offer.date, order.offer.text, order.offer.price, order.amount, order.amount*order.offer.price))
    if not rows:
        return format_html('<div>No orders up to now.</div>')
    return format_html('''Last Orders: 
     <table class="table table-striped">
      <tr><th>Date</th><th>Text</th><th>Price</th><th class="col-1">Amount</th><th>Sum</th></tr>
      {}
     </table>
     ''', join(rows))
```

Is PyCharm able to do HTML Syntax checking and highlighting in Python strings like above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! PyCharm can do both...

To have both functionalities in a Python string containing HTML first requires using an IDE functionality called *"Language injections"*.

In the context of the IDE *"Syntax checks"* are usually called *"Inspections"* and *"Syntax highlighting"* is under *"Color Scheme"*, as follows (compare with the Python entries in the same sections):

| Functionalities | IDE path to dialogue |
| --- | --- |
| Syntax checks | `Settings` `>` `Editor` `>` `Inspections` `>` `HTML` |
| Syntax highlights | `Settings` `>` `Editor` `>` `Color Sheme` `>` `HTML` |

**Using Language Injections:**

The best guide I've found on the JetBrains site is: ["Language injections (for IntelliJ IDEA)"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-language-injections.html), it follows the exact same steps as the [guide for the PyCharm IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/language-injections-settings.html#InjectionEntriesList) but is more elaborate. (I also liked this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obEqd83YugU) that shows how to do *"Language injections"* for several different languages.)

I used the following Python code [separating the string with a backslash `\`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2059025) because it's easier for seeing syntax error warnings on separate lines:

```py
# language=HTML prefix=<body> suffix=<body>
your_python_string = '\
    <body text=""><h1>some header text</h1></body>\
    t<br></br> \
    <dir>\
    '
```

Having said that, lets configure the functionalities:

Start by clicking inside the Python string literal and press <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> or click in light bulb pop-up; choose *"Inject language or reference"* and next choose *"HTML"* as show below, the background color of the string literal should change:

[image: image of configuring language injections]

**Syntax checks (or Inspections) to the HTML:**

At this point if you press <kbd>Alt + 6</kbd> (running `Inspect Code` gives additional warnings) there should be a docked window with the HTML warnings and syntax check. You will also have HTML code hints available:

[image: image of warnings and code hints working]

**Syntax highlights:**

[This dialogue is integrated into the PyCharm per language](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html#customize-color-scheme), after having activated *"Language injection"* for the string literal it already has HTML specific highlight, you can adjust the color scheme for better contrast to your preference:

[image: adjusting syntax highlight]

**A final thought:**

The warnings that are emitted by PyCharm for HTML are shown in the screenshot below. Other functionalities [associated with HTML files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/editing-html-files.html) are also available in the HTML injected string.

[image: image of HTML inspections]

Answer (score 0):

@guettli As far as I know, PyCharm will just see embedded HTML code as string because of the `'` `'` used around the HTML code.