# Does PyCharm have a per line marker for SQL dialect?

Tags: pycharm

I have a Python codebase that uses SQLite and MariaDB. For the most part, I can always specify the SQL dialect per file. As the code changes and is updated I'd like to have a marker, similar to `# noinspection <CheckToSupress>`, that I can use to mark the dialect locally. For example:

```py
# ... python code
# sql dialect mariadb
results = cursor.execute('select * from my_mariadb table');
# ...python code
```

Does the PyCharm IDE have such a per line marker for the SQL dialect?

Comment: Use SQL language injection like shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66557880) and [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65575973)

Comment: Where does the `cursor` come from? The question is missing the import.