# Continuing a long dictionary value in Python due to line length

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to continue a dictionary value to the next line because it's too long but appears to still not be right. I have it broken up but apparently the indentation is now wrong too. Any ideas about how to best format this?
[image]

Comment: Provide  code that you have tried.

Comment: What do you mean by "indentation is now wrong"? You are probably missing the space between `to` and `be`. But apart from that, that looks right.

Comment: try replacing " with ''' and make it 1 line.

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). As well, please provide runnable code. What you've got pictured here is just a fragment. For reference see [mre].

Comment: What's the problem with the indentation? That looks valid, so you shouldn't get an `IndentationError` or anything like that, but maybe you're getting a linter error/warning? For example, pycodestyle says `E128 continuation line under-indented for visual indent [pep8]`, though it goes away if you remove the parentheses.

Comment: @Kral *"make it 1 line"* -- how does that help? OP wants to split a long line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I break up this long line in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058925/how-can-i-break-up-this-long-line-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

**String literal concatenation**

```
d = {"question": ("this is "
                  "long data")}
print(d)
```

Comment: You don't actually need a backslash here due to [string literal concatenation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation)

Comment: Thank you for the inforamtion.

Answer (score 0):

```
long_dict = {
    "key": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, "
           "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
}
```

EDIT:

Why this works: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation (thanks @wjandrea )

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.